# phpmyadmin - import sql.zip file

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I have LEMP dropet on digital ocean and setup phpmyadmin. It is working fine but I can't import script.sql.zip file. I got following error.

You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/zip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.

May I know what configuration I need to change?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install php-zip to solve it.

```
aptitude search php | grep zip
aptitude install php-zip
```

Or simple unzip it, and then try to upload.